# How can I test when app requires OTP via SMS?

Tags: automated-testing, java, tools, integration-testing, api

I'm using `Selenium` with `Java` to test a `web application`. The app requires a user to receive a `One-Time Passcode (OTP)` to authenticate they are, who they say they are and to authorize several critical transactions.

I have the automation code for the `web application` itself, but I need something methodology for the `OTP`, which is sent via `SMS/text` to a `mobile device`.

I know I need some `API/Web service`, that will emulate a phone, allow me to query it and return the message sent to it.

I have looked at `Twilio` and a few other such services, but they require you to start the process with them. Such as by sending an `SMS` to request an `OTP`, and then they will send back an `OTP` back for you to consume. But the app has its own `OTP generator`, so `Twilio` and such will not work for me.

Anyone have any suggestions or examples I can borrow?

Comment: Do any of the options here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327117/reading-sms-using-appium-on-android) help?

Comment: Cannot by-pass OTP, as that is part of the current testing and future regression tests. Do not have Appium. While I have my own cell phone, I would prefer a virtual phone that others can use as well.

Comment: Any reason to not remove it via feature flags and test OTP separately? Login is a small portion of the usage of most apps - after the user has the access token, login systems do not enter in the scene.

Comment: The OTP functionality also includes some other business function that needs to be tested. the OTP is configurable on/off but needs to be tested.

Answer (score 2):

Another option you could try is Google Voice (voice.google.com). This will give you a web interface to a phone number which is free for your first number.

I have used the app to test two factor authentication, so it should work for at least manual testing of your scenario.

Google allows you to have one number without charge, but you need to pay for any extra numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate so that you configure a Flow which monitors incoming SMS messages and dumpd them to a file. Then you mount file system of your phone to your pc where the tests are being executed (e.g. by pluging it via a cord) hence making your automated tests monitor the folder and parse data income.

Comment: Wish to take the actual phone out of the picture, or not be dependent upon my phone.

Comment: Im afraid it is hardly possible. You will need the device which would be registered in mobile network in order to accept SMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key to store last OTP in an in-memory storage like Redis or closured Dictionary in your backend language, you will then update this key with the value of the OTP you want to send out via an SMS service provider. The last sent OTP stored in this key should then be exposed via an additional api endpoint in your service, which you would then call as part of your automated script after doing an action that will make the OTP to be sent.

A more reliable and robust modification of this will be to expose an API that retrieves the OTP stored against each phone number, you must have this stored already of course before you could do the verification in-app. This endpoint must only be exposed within a test environment, that's the precaution to pay attention to, or you make the endpoint available only to authorized user roles.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test OTP authentication in a web application, you can simulate an SMS-based OTP in a few different ways. One option is to:

Write a script that generates the OTP and sends it to a virtual phone number.
Have your test code retrieve the OTP from the virtual phone number.
Use the retrieved OTP in your test code to complete the authentication process.
Another option is to use an SMS gateway service that provides a virtual phone number and an API for retrieving incoming messages. You can configure your application to send the OTP to this virtual phone number and then retrieve it in your test code using the API.

It's important to note that you should not use real phone numbers for testing, as it may result in unwanted SMS messages being sent to real people.

Examples of SMS gateway services include:

- Twilio
- Nexmo
- Plivo

You can also use a mock SMS gateway service, such as WireMock, to simulate the OTP generation and sending process.